# Passing variables to a `Relay.QL`

Tags: relayjs, relay

Theres a way to catch variables using a *Relay.QL* like this example?

**SubredditQuery.js**

```
import Relay from 'react-relay'

const SubredditQuery = {
  subreddit: () => Relay.QL`
    query {
      subreddit(name: "Futurology")
    }
  `,
}

export default SubredditQuery
```

**App.js**

```
export default createRenderer(ReactNativeRelay, {
  queries: SubredditQuery,
  fragments: {
    subreddit: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on RedditSubreddit {
        title
        hotListings {
          title
          score
          url
          author {
            username
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
})
```

I need to use *variable* ***$name*** instead of hardcoded *"Futurology"*. Is there any way? Thanks

Comment: Late comment, but I just saw this now. Where is the variable set?

Comment: In
*query {
  subreddit(name: "Futurology")
}*

The "Futurology" in *name* should be a variable